# SQL - select rows not similar to above in the same column in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the following result when I tried to fetch the results from the database with **mysql** command :

`select player_id,full_name,club_name from players`

something like that :

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Wael Gamal   |   ENPPI     |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   Petrojet  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | Mohamed mezo |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

but I have many **club names** similar to above

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

**OR**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | Mohamed mezo |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

and I have tried to use `ORDER BY RAND(club_name)` and it gave me a result like that

**Ex:**

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   Petrojet  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Wael Gamal   |   ENPPI     |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | Mohamed mezo |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | Mohamed gad  |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

The desired output would be:

```
+----+------+---------------------+
| id |   full_name  |  club_name  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 1  | Ahmed Sayed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 2  | Kareem Gaber |   Petrojet  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 3  | Wael Gamal   |   ENPPI     |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 4  | Mohab Saeed  |   El Ahly   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 5  | Kamal saber  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 6  | Mohamed mezo |   Ismaily   |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 7  | Mohamed gad  |   Cocorico  |
+----+------+---------------------+
| 8  | moaz maged   |   Smouha    |
+----+------+---------------------+
```

can **mysql** do that or should I integrate **php** with **mysql** ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to select from the clubs with an ordering so no two adjacent rows have the same club.

A close approximation is to interleave the clubs, which you can do with a subquery and variables:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             (@rn := if(@c = club, @rn + 1,
                        if(@c := club, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from players p cross join
           (select @c := '', @rn := 0) params
      order by club
     ) p
order by rn, club;
```

There are circumstances where this doesn't work.  But if you clubs have a similar number of members, it should be ok.

Comment: thanks for your reply this is exactly what i want but could you please tell me if i have many many similar club names for example 5 similar club name or more ? and please explain your mysql query .

Comment: please any other solution if i have many number of members in the same club ?

Comment: @authprivate . . . Could you ask another question with sample data that is unbalanced?  The solution is likely to be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you don't want that the players with same club names would appear one after another in your result set.

Probably, the query you need is the following:

```
SELECT p2.id, p2.full_name, p2.club_name
FROM (
    SELECT 
        id,
        @row_number := CASE
            WHEN @clubName = club_name THEN @row_number + 1
            ELSE 1
        END AS sort_num,
        full_name,
        @clubName := club_name as club_name
    FROM
        players p1
    ORDER BY p1.club_name
) AS p2 ORDER BY p2.sort_num, p2.id;
```

Let me try to explain. You need to order your rows by some column, which will contain unique number for every non-unique club name. There is a very nice feature in Oracle DB called ROW_NUMBER. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have it. So we are emulating it.

Subquery

```
SELECT 
    id,
    @row_number := CASE
        WHEN @clubName = club_name THEN @row_number + 1
        ELSE 1
    END AS sort_num,
    full_name,
    @clubName := club_name as club_name
FROM
    players p1
ORDER BY p1.club_name;
```

will produce the following result:

```
+----+----------+--------------+-----------+
| id | sort_num | full_name    | club_name |
+----+----------+--------------+-----------+
|  5 |        1 | Kamal saber  | Cocorico  |
|  1 |        1 | Ahmed Sayed  | El Ahly   |
|  2 |        2 | Kareem Gaber | El Ahly   |
|  3 |        1 | Wael Gamal   | ENPPI     |
|  6 |        1 | Mohamed mezo | Ismaily   |
|  7 |        2 | Mohamed gad  | Ismaily   |
|  4 |        1 | Mohab Saeed  | Petrojet  |
|  8 |        1 | moaz maged   | Smouha    |
+----+----------+--------------+-----------+
```

Pay attention to the sort_num column. For rows with club name "El Ahly" it has two unqiue values 1 and 2. Now all we do is sorting by this column.

The final result:

```
+----+--------------+-----------+
| id | full_name    | club_name |
+----+--------------+-----------+
|  1 | Ahmed Sayed  | El Ahly   |
|  3 | Wael Gamal   | ENPPI     |
|  4 | Mohab Saeed  | Petrojet  |
|  5 | Kamal saber  | Cocorico  |
|  6 | Mohamed mezo | Ismaily   |
|  8 | moaz maged   | Smouha    |
|  2 | Kareem Gaber | El Ahly   |
|  7 | Mohamed gad  | Ismaily   |
+----+--------------+-----------+
```

Comment: thanks for your replay but your mysql query not shown the result as same as the following result or the final result appreciate your effort .